# Bootstrap "Starter template": When is the menu-icon/button shown/hidden?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm studying the Bootstrap "[Starter template](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/)" and I can't figure out when the menu-icon/button (With the three horizontal lines) is shown.

*The template is located in the Bootstrapfolder:* bootstrap-3.3.6\docs\examples\starter-template

At what whith of the .container (or the .navbar-header) is it shown/hidden?
Or rather: What triggers it and where can I change it?

Comment: It's triggered in the CSS via media queries (at certain screen sizes, the one menu will be hidden and the icon will be shown - and vice-versa)

Comment: it should be in the CSS for navbar.  I've not looked personally, but I'm guessing it's a media query

Comment: Thanks, I found it in the Bootstrap CSS. I don't know why I missed it before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A media query in the file: bootstrap.css on line 4366.

```
   @media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
```